# BLE Clarifying the Read and Indicate Operations

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, micropython, bluetooth-gatt

I'm writing code for Pycom's Lopy4 board and have created a BLE service for environmental sensing which currently has one characteristic, temperature. I'm taking the temperature as a float and attempting to update the characteristic value every two seconds.

When I use a BLE scanner app, whenever I try to read, I read a value of "temperature10862," which is the characteristic's name and uuid. Yet when I press the indicate button, the value shows the correct temperature string, updating automatically every two seconds.

I'm a bit confused overall. Is this a problem with my code on the Pycom device or am I simply misunderstanding what a BLE read is supposed to be? Since the temperature values are obviously being updated on the device, but why does the client, the app, only show these values with an indication rather than a read?

I am sorry for any vagueness in the question, but any help or guidance would be appreciated.

[Read Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpupa.jpg)
[Indicate Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyJwO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Returning "temperature10862" as a read response is obviously incorrect. Sending the temperature as a string is in this case also incorrect, since you use the Bluetooth SIG-defined characteristic https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature.xml. According to that the value should consist of a signed 16-bit integer in units of 0.01 degrees Celcius.

If you look at https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.environmental_sensing.xml, you will see that it's mandatory to support Read and optional to support Notifications. Indications, however are not permitted. So you should change your indicate property to notify instead.

The value sent should be the same regardless if the value is sent as a notification or read response.

Be sure you read the Environmental Sensing specs and follow the rest of the GATT service structure.